# Simple string.Format question for <a ... class="button" in mvc

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3, string.format

Example link

```
<div style="float:right;"><a href="<%= Url.Content("~/Home/List") %>" class="button"><span>Return to List</span></a></div>
```

I want to be able to attach an Id onto the end of the url which is from my Model like shown below in one of my many attempts

```
<div style="float:right;">(string.Format(<a href=\"{0}\{1}" %>, <% Url.Content("~/Test/Edit")%>, <% Model.Test.ID %>) "class="button"><span>Edit</span></a></div>
```

I know how to do it with action links but I want to keep to the same format and produce a button.

I know this works

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { Id = Model.Test.ID }) %>
```

So anybody got as ideas for a solution?

Thx.

Comment: Hi, are you aware of benefits of using the ActionLink HTML helper?

Comment: @CodeRush I believe I am but could just be briefly so feel free to enlighten me as long as you think it could still return the same end visual result (project users r kinder computer iliterate so every little bit helps to make it more user friendly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div style="float:right;">
    <a href="<%: string.Format("{0}/{1}", Url.Content("~/Test/Edit"), Model.Test.ID) %>" class="button">
        <span>Edit</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

should do it, although you could use [`Url.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460348.aspx) here

```
<div style="float:right;">
    <a href="<%: Url.Action("Edit", "Test", new { id = Model.Test.ID }) %>" class="button">
        <span>Edit</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

The main benefit of using `Url.Action` is that you have not tied yourself to any particular URL routing scheme, but to the controllers and action methods, thereby allowing you to change the routing when and how you please.

Comment: thx both will be useful but I'll most likely switch to using Url.Action now since it's less hassle. p.s. in you 1st answer you missed the ")" after "Model.Test.ID" once that's in it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use actionlink for this if u just want to add a class to it

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { @id = Model.Test.ID }, new { @class = "button" }) %>
```

This will produce the same thing as if u were to use the other method.

Comment: But then this doesn't include the `<span>Edit</span>` inside the generated `<a>` element which it sounds like the OP wants to keep

Comment: if this solution works then it would still display Edit in the button so it's a valid point worth an upvote but your answer Russ is a direct answer to the precise question asked so now that I can accept after 5min wait I've accepted yours Russ

Comment: It half works and by this I mean literally only half the button displays with all the text so I'm guessing I'd have to reconfigue the button css to resolve this but still it's the most ideal solution to keep it upto date with the latest mvc style hence my upvote.